# Newton Interpolating Polynomial First Derivative

Tags: calculus

I need to find where the Newtons interpolating polynomial is at a minimum, so I have to set its first derivative to 0 and solve for it, although I'm shaving trouble doing this as its obfuscated behind a mass of pi operators and sigma summations, and I cant seem to find any information online, is there a general formula for the first derivative of a nth order Newton polynomial? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Show us what you have done so far, do you have a concrete example with concrete numbers, perhaps with a polynomial of degree 2 for the beginning? If you do know the Newton interpolation scheme with divided differences, there is one which incorporates derivatives. For that one search Hermite interpolation.

Comment: exapanded the formula for a 2nd order polynomial to f(x0) + (f(x0)/(x0-x1) + f(x1) /(x1-x0)) * (x-x0) + (x-x0)(x-x1) ( f(x0)/(x-x0)(x0-x2) + f(x1)/(x1-x0)(x1-x2) +f(x2) /(x2-x0)(x2-x1),

but those all then become constant terms so cant seem to get a usefull derivative out of them,

Comment: only aproach I could see is tto take derivative of the whole formula, whihc brin me back to the original problem

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to do. The newton or hermite interpolation schemes give polynomials, which have specified values for $f$, $f^\prime$, $f^{\prime\prime}$, ... for given points $x_k$. Then you are calculating the derivative of such a polynomial and want to find out where this polynomial has minima and maxima. This might only work, if the resulting polynomial has degrees $\le 5$. For degree $\ge 6$ you'll get a derivative of degree $\ge 5$, where there might be even no formula to get the roots of the derivative. search the Abel-Ruffini theorem.

Comment: D: how come lagrange interplation has a derivitve though?

Comment: I have never said, that the resulting interpolation polynomial doesn't have a derivative. Polynomials always have derivatives. I told you, that you will run into problems finding a general  formula for the maxima and minima of the interpolation polynomial, if its degree is not small enough.

Comment: $$ \sum_{k=0}^{k<=n}\sum_{i=0}^{k} \Pi_{j=0, j \neq i}^{k-1} (x-x_j) $$ seems to be the derivative, sorry that I replied so late, have been busy.

Comment: please read my last comment again, how would you use this formula for general root finding of the derivative??